# Is there a way to find the font used in this image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

Which font is used in this image or how can I find?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use tools like 'What the font'. You can past a screenshot for example and it will search for the font or similar fonts.

Comment: i tried that but didn't get any similar results

Comment: Okay.. You could also try to find the designer who made it or just google for the style like "neon hawaii font" or something. There isn't a lot more you could do.

Answer (score 1):

[Freeze D italic](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Freeze-D-Italic) via fontsgeek.com

The path of the letter "a" is different, I think due to the adaptation to the construction of the neon.

[image]